# Strange Characters reading from sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, replace, utf-8, ascii

I read a String from sqlite db and would like to replace a specific character in my java code.

The field I read shows the name "Frédéric Chopin":

[image]

Now I simply want to replace the 'é' with an '_', but I do not succeed, after replace the name is still the same.

```
    config.setEncoding(SQLiteConfig.Encoding.UTF8);

  rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
  String wikiId = rs.getString("wikiid")
  String newWikiId = wikiId;
  newWikiId = newWikiId.replace("é", "_");
```

Can someone help me howto do this ?

Simplified the issue with only Java Code:

```
@Test
public void misttest(){
    int asciiVal = 233;
    String str = new Character((char) asciiVal).toString();
    String name = "Fr" + str + "d" + str + "ric";
    String newName = name.replace("é", "_");
    System.out.println(newName);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are using Java code to replace, right? This works fine for me.

Comment: When setting the String directly it works, but when reading from sqlite db there must be something special. I updated the question, so you see, that I am reading from sqlite.

Comment: Execute: `System.out.println((int) rs.getString("wikiid").charAt(2));` and `System.out.println((int) 'é');` and compare the results. If they are not th esame this means that the 2 chars are different.

Comment: They are different. I added a new Screenshot. But then how can I replace this with a String ?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Try setting the sqlite encoding to utf-8, using SqliteConfig https://javadoc.io/doc/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.15.1/org/sqlite/SQLiteConfig.html#setEncoding-org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig.Encoding-

Comment: Thanks for helping. This I have already done. not helping. Any other idea ?

Comment: Is this the only strange char that you want to replace?

Comment: No there are a lot, but I try to understand the problem with this case. I added a codesnipped, which simplifies the problem. Its only java code. I would like to replace the char using String.replace. I could of course replace the char, but I need to replace with Strings.

Comment: Try: `String newName = name.replace((char) 233 + "", "_");` if 233 is the code of the strange char.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I would like to replace with a String. Sounds strange, but I can't replace a converted char in my case. The User should be able to give replacements as Strings.